# Printing binary tree in python

Tags: python, printing, tree, binary

I want to print my binary tree vertical and the nodes should be random numbers, but output that I get is not what I want. 
For example I receive something like this:

```
497985
406204
477464
```

But program should print this:

```
.....497985
406204
.....477464
```

I don't know where is the problem. Im begginer at programming so if anyone can help me it would be great.

```
from numpy.random import randint
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class binarytree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elem = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def printtree(tree, h):
    if tree is not None:
        printtree(tree.right, h+1)
        for i in range(1, h):
            print(end = ".....")
        print(tree.elem)
        printtree(tree.left, h+1)


def generate(tree, N, h):
    if N == 0:
        tree = None
    else:
        tree = binarytree()
        x = randint(0, 1000000)
        tree.elem = int(x)
        generate(tree.left, N // 2, h)
        generate(tree.right, N - N // 2 - 1, h)
    printtree(tree, h)

tree = binarytree()
generate(tree, 3, 0)
```

Comment: You dont every increment h .. so the range function inside printtree is ```range(1,0) or range(1,1)`` in either case the resulting ranges are zero length so the ```print(end=".....") is never called

Comment: Hello! Your code seems to be a bit confused, currently. You've got a number of unused imports, and `generate` is overwriting its `tree` argument every time you call it - you aren't actually recursively building a tree but you're recursively building lots of singleton trees, and printing all of those. Also it's not very clear to me what the output you're looking for is - could you elaborate at all on how you want the tree to be formatted? (Is the tree growing from the left to the right?)

Answer (score 1):

I've re-written your code to be a little more Pythonic, and fixed what appeared
to be some bugs:

```
from  random import randrange

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    @classmethod
    def generate_random_tree(cls, depth):
        if depth > 0:
            return cls(randrange(1000000),
                       cls.generate_random_tree(depth - 1),
                       cls.generate_random_tree(depth - 1))
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Overloaded method to format tree as string
        """
        return "\n".join(self._format())

    def _format(self, cur_depth=0):
        """
        Format tree as string given current depth. This is a generator of
        strings which represent lines of the representation.
        """
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right._format(cur_depth + 1)
        yield "{}{}".format("." * cur_depth, self.val)
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left._format(cur_depth + 1)

print(BinaryTree.generate_random_tree(4))
print()
print(BinaryTree(1,
                 BinaryTree(2),
                 BinaryTree(3,
                            BinaryTree(4),
                            BinaryTree(5))))
```

This outputs a tree, which grows from the root at the middle-left to leaves at
the right:

```
...829201
..620327
...479879
.746527
...226199
..463199
...498695
987559
...280755
..168727
...603817
.233132
...294525
..927571
...263402

..5
.3
..4
1
.2
```

Here it's printed one random tree, and one tree that I manually constructed.
I've written it so that the "right" subtree gets printed on top - you can switch
this around if you want.

You can make some further adjustments to this by making more dots at once (which
I think was your `h` parameter?), or adapting bits into whatever program
structure you want.

This code works because it makes sure it builds a whole tree first, and then
later prints it. This clear distinction makes it easier to make sure you're
getting all of it right. Your code was a little confused in this regard - your
`generate` function did instantiate a new `BinaryTree` at each call, but you
never attached any of them to each other! This is because when you do
`tree = ...` inside your function, all you're doing is changing what the local
name `tree` points to - it doesn't change the attribute of the tree from higher
up that you pass to it!

Your generate also calls `printtree` every time, but `printtree` also calls
itself... This just doesn't seem like it was entirely right.

In my program, this bit generates the random tree:

```
    def generate_random_tree(cls, depth):
        if depth > 0:
            return cls(randrange(1000000),
                       cls.generate_random_tree(depth - 1),
                       cls.generate_random_tree(depth - 1))
        return None
```

The classmethod bit is just some object-oriented Python stuff that isn't very
important for the algorithm. The key thing to see is that it generates two new
smaller trees, and they end up being the `left` and `right` attributes of the
tree it returns. (This also works because I did a little re-write of
`__init__`).

This bit basically prints the tree:

```
    def _format(self, cur_depth=0):
        """
        Format tree as string given current depth. This is a generator of
        strings which represent lines of the representation.
        """
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right._format(cur_depth + 1)
        yield "{}{}".format("." * cur_depth, self.val)
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left._format(cur_depth + 1)
```

It's a generator of lines - but you could make it directly print the tree by
changing each `yield ...` to `print(...)` and removing the `yield from`s. The
key things here are the `cur_depth`, which lets the function be aware of how
deep in the tree it currently is, so it knows how many dots to print, and the
fact that it recursively calls itself on the left and right subtrees (and you
have to check if they're `None` or not, of course).

(This part is what you could modify to re-introduce `h`).

Comment: ok thank you ! but can you make some futher explanations? i mean i dont think i get whats happening in this code and still it doesnt print what it should becouse all the nodes are pretty much the same.

Comment: Hi @sonia! Can you clarify what it "should" print please? It's not yet very clear to me from your question, I'm afraid! Maybe you could add a bigger example output?

Comment: at each level, your algorithm generates the same numbers. for example if our random numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,6. first line of the output should be: `.....5` second: `..........6` third:`1` fourth: `..........4` and so on  `.....2` and `..........3` , 
numbers or nodes in printed tree cant be doubled .

Comment: Hello again @sonia - you're absolutely right, that wasn't correct behaviour - I'd just written a massive bug, where I was just printing the left subtree twice instead of the left and then the right subtree. I've (hopefully) fixed this and added a little more explanation. Let me know what you'd like me to clarify more!